# Excel count blank cells until next blank cells is found

Tags: excel

I have data like this and I would like to count the number of blank cells between each of two non-blank cells plus 1, like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since your entries in row 1 are numeric, in `B2`:

`=IFNA(IF(B1,XMATCH(1,IF(C1:$XFD1,1)),""),"")`

and copied right.